# Appending an object list with arrays within it's values

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to display a list of objects in a table. But I am getting undefined values back. I have objects within objects and I can't seem to get it to work.

My objects

```
var names = {
  fname : {"Bill", "John"},
  lname : {"Smith", "Evans"},
  age : {"30", "41"}
}
```

I tried a for loop but with no luck

```
for (i in names){
  $("#myTable").append("<tr><td>" + names[i].fname +", "+ names[i].lname +"</td>"+
"<td>"+ names[i].age +"</td></tr>"
);
}
```

my table

```
<table>
 <tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

My goal is to append new entries to the objects list directly into the html table, based on the index of each value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues. First, your input data is invalid:

```
var names = {
  fname : {"Bill", "John"},
  lname : {"Smith", "Evans"},
  age : {"30", "41"}
}
```

Assuming each of these should be an array? For example: `fname: ["Bill", "John" ]`.

Second, you're looping through each *key* of the object (`fname`, `lname`, `age`). Assuming you want to loop through each value of each key?

As long as all the keys will always have the same length, you can choose the first `fname` attribute and loop from `0` to one less than the total length.

```js
var names = {
  fname: [
    "Bill",
    "John"
  ],
  lname: [
    "Smith",
    "Evans"
  ],
  age: [
    "30",
    "41"
  ]
}

for (var i = 0; i < names.fname.length; i++) {
  $("#myTable").append("<tr><td>" + names.fname[i] + ", " + names.lname[i] + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + names.age[i] + "</td></tr>"
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```